Consens sequence of list of strings as multiple sequence alignment?
I'm working on a program whose goal is to make a playlist that "flows" nicely. To do this, I obtain for each song a list of the genres it belongs to from Spotify. I've assumed that the order of this list heuristically goes from "bigger" genres to "nicher" genres. Effectively, my data structure here is a list of list of strings [["rock", "American rock", "synth rock"], ["rock", "French rock", "synth rock"], ["pop", "rock", "alt rock"]].
Now, in order to figure out how to order my playlist, I need a "consensus sequence" of all the genres. Because I have a computational biology background, my first thought was to try to align these lists together and obtain a consensus from that alignment.
Do you know of any packages that implement such an algorithm on sets of strings rather than DNA/RNA/Protein alphabets in python?

Sounds like a fun project! I don't have a comp bio background, so I can't speak to the usage of those sorts of alignment algorithms, but from a natural language processing perspective, this seems to resemble a Bag-of-Words setup, just with the goal of looking at the alignment/overlap/similarity of two bags rather than converting these bags into something that would be fed to a machine learning model. You could thus compute similarity of two songs as follows:
def similarity(
    genres_1: list[str], genres_2: list[str], type: str = "genre_set"
) -> float:
    """
    Compute the similarity between two lists of genres.

    Parameters
    ----------
    genres_1 : list[str]
        A list of genres.
    genres_2 : list[str]
        A list of genres.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        A value between 0 and 1 (inclusive) representing the similarity between the two lists of genres.
    """
    match type:
        case "genre_set":
            genre_set_1, genre_set_2 = set(genres_1), set(genres_2)
            intersection = len(genre_set_1 & genre_set_2)
            union = len(genre_set_1 | genre_set_2)
        case "word_set":
            word_set_1, word_set_2 = set(" ".join(genres_1).split()), set(
                " ".join(genres_2).split()
            )
            intersection = len(word_set_1 & word_set_2)
            union = len(word_set_1 | word_set_2)

    return intersection / union

Here, type="genre_set" indicates that you only care if two songs overlap exactly for the name of a given genre whereas type="word_set" indicates that two songs with genres "Classic Funk Rock" and "Classic Psychedelic Rock" would get some similarity points for having "classic" and "rock" in common even though the whole genres don't match.
If you want to get even fancier about this, you could look into using TF-IDF vectorization, which weighs the importance of overlap based on how often various words show up (and so two songs which have a rare genre word in common would be more similar than ones with a common genre word in common). At a quick glance, this tutorial seems like it could be useful.
